# Spring Data Rest + Spring Boot - findBy* not passing parameter to MongoDB?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have a spring boot web app (with jetty) using the spring-data-rest project, and I can't get a parameter from a GET request to pass down to the mongo query.

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but need some guidance to what.

TL;DR... search/query =>

```
$ http GET localhost:8080/rules/search/findByName?test2  # <-- NOTE 'test2'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/hal+json; charset=UTF-8
Date: Fri, 20 Mar 2015 13:54:35 GMT
Server: Jetty(9.2.9.v20150224)
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Application-Context: application

{}
```

Mongo saw =>

```
> db.system.profile.find({op:"query", ns: "test.rule"}, {query: 1}). sort({ts:-1}).pretty()
{ "query" : { "name" : null } }    # <-- Note *NOT* 'test2'
```

Longer Story...

I have a simple "Rule" class with nothing but an id and name.

```
public class Rule {
    private String id;
    private String name;
// getters/setters removed for brevity.
}
```

My Repository exposes a `findByName()` method.

```
@RestResource
interface RuleRepository extends CrudRepository<Rule, String> {
    List<Rule> findByName(@Param("name") String name)
}
```

When I POST to the spring boot app, it works fine.  I can see the data in the mongo database perfectly.

(using the `httpie` application to post...)

```
$ http POST localhost:8080/rules name="test2"
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Content-Length: 0
Date: Fri, 20 Mar 2015 13:49:02 GMT
Location: http://localhost:8080/rules/550c254e87867064832263b3
Server: Jetty(9.2.9.v20150224)
X-Application-Context: application
```

mongo...

```
> db.rule.find({})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("550c254e87867064832263b3"), "_class" : "<package>.Rule", "name" : "test2" }
```

Things look OK up to this point.

```
$ http GET localhost:8080/rules
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/hal+json; charset=UTF-8
Date: Fri, 20 Mar 2015 13:51:36 GMT
Server: Jetty(9.2.9.v20150224)
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Application-Context: application

{  "_embedded": { "rules": [  ... brevity.  Everything is here that should be ...
```

And the search resource looks ok.

```
$ http GET localhost:8080/rules/search
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/hal+json; charset=UTF-8
Date: Fri, 20 Mar 2015 13:51:47 GMT
Server: Jetty(9.2.9.v20150224)
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Application-Context: application

{
    "_links": {
        "findByName": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/rules/search/findByName{?name}",
            "templated": true
        }
    }
}
```

But when I search, nothing returns, and mongo reports the query as having been passed a null.

```
$ http GET localhost:8080/rules/search/findByName?test2
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/hal+json; charset=UTF-8
Date: Fri, 20 Mar 2015 13:54:35 GMT
Server: Jetty(9.2.9.v20150224)
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Application-Context: application

{}
```

Mongo...

```
> db.system.profile.find({op:"query", ns: "test.rule"}, {query: 1}). sort({ts:-1}).pretty()
{ "query" : { "name" : null } }
```

Comment: Your request should be `localhost:8080/rules/search/findByName?name=test2`

Comment: Dammit, you're right.  That works great.  Thanks.  (If you put this as an answer, I'll be glad to "check" it as correct.)

Comment: Ok, I will do that. :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your request should be `localhost:8080/rules/search/findByName?name=test2`. As stated in the `HATEOAS` response of `localhost:8080/rules/search`:

```
{
    "_links": {
        "findByName": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/rules/search/findByName{?name}",
            "templated": true
        }
    }
}
```

`findByName{?name}` ⟶ `findByName?name=ABC`

Comment: Thanks (again).  The `{?name}` threw me - thought it meant PUT YOUR NAME HERE.

Comment: I searched for a documentation for this but I didn't found any. :-/